# 2 update statements are executed almost at the same time

Tags: java, mysql, database

Using Spring Boot Data, 2 update statements are executed sequence but almost at the same time (maybe 1 or 2 nano seconds) as below:

> Update StatusTable SET status = 'IN-PROGRESS' AND updatedTime = NOW();
>
> Update StatusTable SET status = 'DONE' AND updatedTime = NOW();

2 update statements return updatedTime with **same value**.

In UI, I have a screen where display StatusTable in chronological order based on updatedTime. Because of same updatedTime, it displays wrong order:

1) READY

2) IN-PROGRESS

instead of

1) IN-PROGRESS

2) READY

Note: Thread.sleep() or delay time isn't a good option to go in my case

Comment: Well, you display those two rows in an arbitrary order, or you choose an acdditional sort criterion to decide what comes first in case of a tie. What's the problem?

Comment: in chronological order based on updatedTime.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. You have two things happening at the same time. That happens. What's the big deal?

Comment: I updated my post to state problem clearer.

Comment: If that is always the order you are updating in, or rather, if you want the status "done" always displayed after the "in-progress", then you can order by the status second (so e.g. `order by updatedTime, status desc` (or not `desc` if you use "ready" instead of "done") or something similar.

Comment: Is `currentTime` value updated? I mean did you check that you are not using the same variable for the 2 statements? And what's the precision? (seconds, millis, ..?)

Comment: Are you using an ORM to do this? If so which?

Comment: There is no order for status. it can be changed from READY to IN-PROGRESS and vice versa. Only Updated Time is used to specify order

Comment: Well according to chronolical ordering logic, that is totally valid order - you simply have 2 same timestamps, so how do you know which was "first"? Answer is none - happened in the same time. Stop using the same timestamp for 2 events and you will be fine or at least start using greater precision - miliseconds maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you are using timestamp with seconds precision right? Start using finer precision like mili or microseconds precision. If this does not help (cuz you are using blazing fast computer and 2 calls to NOW() gives the same nanosecond reading) you will have to find another solution, and stop depending on timestamps.

As a workaround, I would switch or (at least add) to ordering by autoincremented ID. If your SQL follows "chronogical ordering" then IDS will be unique and in the same order.

If you have autoincrement ID, I would try `ORDER BY updatedTime ASC, id ASC` this will cause sorting by id when timestampts are equal, but to be hostest I think that ordering only by `id` would give you desired results.